# Truncation function not working

Tags: php, mysql, function, truncate

I am pulling some data from a mysql database and building a table with it. I have a truncation function to chop down very long strings.

Here is the truncation function:

```
    function myTruncate($string, $limit, $break=".", $pad="...")
    {
      // return with no change if string is shorter than $limit
      if(strlen($string) <= $limit) return $string;

      // is $break present between $limit and the end of the string?
      if(false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $limit))) {
        if($breakpoint < strlen($string) - 1) {
          $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad;
        }
      }
      return $string;
    }
```

Here is the table building bit where the function is called:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($liveItemQuery)){
       //get donation type
       $content .= "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td><td>" . $row['timestamp'] . "</td><td>" . myTruncate($row['description'], 25) . "</td><td>" . $row['po_number'] . "</td><td>" . number_format($row['amount'], 2) . "</td><td><a href=\"?view=expenses&itemid=" . $row['id'] . "\">Edit</a></td></tr>";
       $i++;
   }
```

That being said, truncation is not being performed on the description field. It may be worth noting that `description` is stored as datatype `text` in the database. Also, a var dump of `myTruncate($row['description'], 25)` reports `string(1995)`, the full length of the text.

So what is going on?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Your function truncates at first `$break` found (dot by default) by design...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, ah, I see. So how could it be changed to truncate no matter what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Truncate no matter what". Much easier.

```
function myTruncate($s, $len){
    return substr($s, 0, $len) . (strlen($s)>$len? '...':'');
}
```